# How do I join two array and create json array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

SO I have array1 with values `["folderid":"DTSZ", "folderid":"IEACF6FVGG", "folderid":"IEACKQC6A"]`  and another array 2 with values `["title":"firsttitle", "title":"second","title":"thirdtitle"]`

Now lets say using javascript i want to save it as json object.

```
 [

      {"folderid":"DTSZ","title":"firsttitle"},                
      {"folderid":"IEACF6FVGG", "title":"second"},
      {"folderid":"IEACKQC6A", "title":"thirdtitle"}
 ]
```

I trying looping and concat but didn't work properly.

```
array1= ["folderid":"DTSZ", "folderid":"IEACF6FVGG", "folderid":"IEACKQC6A"] ;

array2 = ["title":"firsttitle", "title":"second","title":"thirdtitle"];
```

Get array with json objects

```
[
      {"folderid":"DTSZ","title":"firsttitle"},                
      {"folderid":"IEACF6FVGG", "title":"second"},
      {"folderid":"IEACKQC6A", "title":"thirdtitle"}
 ]
```

Comment: Your arrays are somewhat invalid.

Comment: In JS, there is no associative array. Therefore `["folderid":"DTSZ"]` is an invalid syntax. You need to set them as objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript an array has just values, in you examples the array is invalid since you try to add direct `key: values` elements . i.e.

`["folderid":"DTSZ"] // invalid !! (notice semicolon)`

`["folderid", "DTSZ"] // VALID (notice comma)`

If you want to translate to a valid array and then to an object, you could use something like entries, which are array of arrays.

Let's take your first example and convert it to entries:

`const arr1 = [["folderid", "DTSZ"], ["folderid", "IEACF6FVGG"], ["folderid","IEACKQC6A"]]`

Then to convert this to object you can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) just like this:

`const obj1 = Object.fromEntries(entries);`

So, focus first to convert your initial invalid arrays to entries, and then the job is done!

Answer (score 0):

use the following code.

```js
var a = [{ "folderid": "DTSZ" }, { "folderid": "IEACF6FVGG" }, { "folderid": "IEACKQC6A" }]
var b = [{ "title": "firsttitle" }, { "title": "second" }, { "title": "thirdtitle" }]


var newObject = a.map((o, index) => {
    const temp = Object.assign(o, b[index]);
   return temp;
});

console.log('output ----  ', newObject)
```